# Redis MULTI command on NodeJS Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, redis

I have been trying to use the `MULTI` command with redis on Heroku, it works well a couple of times but soon or later it stops working and returns 'QUEUED'. It always happens when I use `MULTI`.

```
redis.multi()
    .hgetall('project:' + url)
    .hgetall('code:' + url)
    .exec(function (err, results) {
        //...
    });
```

It's working fine on my local machine but it crashes on Heroku all the time.

Why does 'QUEUED' means here? Has anyone had this issue on Heroku?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which npm module does that use for redis?  I am not using redis on Heroku so I don't know if this applies to the specific module you are using, but the one I have been using has bugs on certain newer versions that have been giving me a lot of problems.  For example https://github.com/mranney/node_redis/issues/289

If its node_redis, you might try 0.7.3, or the latest version from master.

Comment: I am using 'redis-url' 0.1.0 to make it work on heroku, I have just manually updated the 'redis' module dependency to 0.8.2 and it's working now. Thanks Jason.